# Proving upper bound, sum over a product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I'd like to proof the following inequality for $d,D \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{D} \binom{D}{k}\binom{d+D-k-1}{D-1} \leq 2D d^{D-1}.
$$

In case $B>A$ we define $\binom{A}{B}:=0$.

This upper bound is exact in the case $D=1,2$. I'm not quite sure how tackle this problem in a somewhat elegant way.

Comment: for $k > d$ the elements are $0$, so for $d=2$ we get that the expression is equal to $\binom{D}{0}\binom{D+1}{D - 1} +  \binom{D}{1}\binom{D}{D-1} +\binom{D}{2}\binom{D-1}{D-1}= \binom{D+1}{2} +   D^2 + \binom{D}{2} = O(D^2)$ which will be less then than the RHS for sufficiently large $D$'s as it's exponential

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. I meant D=1,2 instead of d=1,2. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof has two parts:

1. We give a combinatorial interpretation of the left hand side; by double counting, this will yield an equivalent sum;
2. Term-by-term inequality will give the desired result.

Let's interpret the left hand side.
Let $S$ be a set of $D$ elements, and $T$ a set of $d-1$ elements.
The LHS counts the number of ways of choosing $A \subset S, B \subset S \cup T$ disjoint, with $|B| = D-1$. In your sum, $k$ denote the number of elements of $A$: the first binomial counts the number of ways of choosing $A$, and the other binomial counts the number of ways of choosing $B$ from the remaining $(D-k)+(d-1)$ elements.

This is equivalent to counting subsets $X \subset S, Y \subset S, Z \subset T$ disjoint such that $|Y| +|Z| = D-1$: $A$ becomes $X$, and $B$ becomes $(B \cap S) \cup (B \cap T) = Y \cup Z$. We count these triples by firstly choosing $Y$, then $Z$, then $X$. In this way we get ($j$ is the cardinality of $Y$):

$$ LHS = \sum_{j=0}^{D-1} \binom{D}{j} \binom{d-1}{D-1-j} 2^{D-j} $$

Can you see that? $Y$ is a subset of $S$ of $j$ elements, $Z$ is a subset of $T$ of the left-to-choose $D-1-j$ elements, and $X$ is a subset of $S\setminus Y$.

Here it comes the algebraic part. We will use that:

- $$\binom{D}{j} = \frac{D!}{(D-j)! j!} = \frac{D}{D-j} \frac{(D-1)!}{(D-j-1)! j!} = \frac{D}{D-j} \binom{D-1}{j} $$
- $ 2^n \le (n+1)!$ indeed, it is satisfied for $n=0,1$, and thereafter the rhs grows faster than the LHS.
- $$\binom{m}{k} = \frac{m (m-1) \ldots (m-k+1)}{k!} \le \frac{m^k}{k!}$$

Hence, we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{D-1} \binom{D}{j} \binom{d-1}{D-1-j} 2^{D-j} = \sum_{j=0}^{D-1} \frac{D}{D-j}\binom{D-1}{j} \binom{d-1}{D-1-j} 2^{D-j} \le  $$
$$ D \sum_{j=0}^{D-1} \frac{1}{D-j}\binom{D-1}{j} \frac{(d-1)^{D-1-j}}{(D-1-j)!} 2^{D-j} = 2D \sum_{j=0}^{D-1} \binom{D-1}{j} \frac{(d-1)^{D-1-j}}{(D-j)!} 2^{D-1-j} \le $$
$$ 2D \sum_{j=0}^{D-1} \binom{D-1}{j}(d-1)^{D-1-j} = 2Dd^{D-1} $$

as desired.

Comment: Don't you mean to say $|B|=D-1$? And that $B\subseteq S\cup T$, since $B$ can include the elements of $S$ which are not in $A$?

Comment: Not only there were typos, but it was wrong :) now I corrected it! It feels like a miracle that terms of the new sum arranges in such a way XD

Comment: Thank you very much. I am particularly amazed by the first step using double counting.

Comment: Nicely done :^)